# get the html of a div and inject it beside another div

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML structure in this format:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sub">123</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sub">abc</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sub">foo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see above, I have 3 equal `div` elements, each with a different `.sub` div.
How can I get the HTML content of `.sub` div and put it NEXT TO `.name` div using jQuery when document is ready?

The results will  be like:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="sub">123</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sub">123</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="sub">abc</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sub">abc</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="sub">foo</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sub">foo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".sub").each(function() {
    $(this).clone().insertAfter($(this).parent().siblings(".name"));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4EMbM/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(.name).after( /*....*/ )
```